# Inotify max file limit

Tags: reactjs, electron, redhat, inotify

I am programming react app with electron in a docker environment.
When I try to `npm run dev`, I got the following error :

```
Error from chokidar (/home/app/mountpoint/Matres-GUI/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime): Error: ENOSPC: System limit for number of file watchers reached, watch '/home/app/mountpoint/Matres-GUI/node_modules/@pmmmwh/react-refresh-webpack-plugin/lib/runtime'
```

But I can't increase the amount of inotify watchers because I have no root access to edit `/etc/sysctl.conf`

Is there a way to drop all the watchers set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a solution [here](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1049)

Just add `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true npm start` to a local `.env` file